# Find a Cthulhu Mythos quotation from Lin Carter

Tags: story-identification, cthulhu-mythos, poetry

I have read a few books about fantasy by Lin Carter, and if I remember correctly one of them had a poem by Lin Carter based on the *King in Yellow* by Robert W. Chambers.

As most of you should know, *The King in Yellow* (1895) is a short story collection by Robert W. Chambers.  Some of the stories mention a being called The King in Yellow and a fictional play titled *The King in Yellow*.

One story ("The Mask") quotes [these lines from the play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_in_Yellow#The_play_called_The_King_in_Yellow):

> Camilla:  You, sir, should unmask.
> Stranger:  Indeed?
> Cassilda:  Indeed it's time. We have all laid aside disguise but you.
> Stranger:  I wear no mask.
> Camilla: (Terrified, aside to Cassilda.) No mask? No mask!

And I remember that one of the lines in the Lin Carter poem I mentioned was something like:

> Do not seek to know, nor ask,
> what lies beneath the pallid mask.

And I have an idea for a story where a character is asked by members of another species to show their face and, knowing the others would be grossed out, and remembering the Lin Carter poem, replies:

> Do not think to know, nor ask,
> what is behind my gilded mask.

So I would like to know what book and chapter that poem can be found in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it [here on page 284 in *The Hastur Cycle*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sxhiog7Y8EAC&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> XXXIII.  The Candidate
>
> Down the street of monoliths I passes,
> The shambling, faceless figure of my Guide
> A voiceless thing that beckoned to my side
> And to the dreaded Gate I came at last.
> Before the silent Guardian I made
> The black unhallowed Sacrifice, and spoke
> Names at whose sound forgotten echoes woke.
> The portals gaped.  I entered unafraid.
> Fate, or my stars, or some accursed pride
> Had brought me here.  Naked, I stood alone
> And to the Vow before the Elder Throne—
> He laughed, and drew His tattered Mantle wide—
> O do not seek to learn nor ever ask
> What horror hides behind... *The Pallid Mask*!

It apparently first appeared in *Amra*, March 1965.  (While *Amra*, as one of the most famous fanzines of all time, is something that one might expect to be able to read online these days, I cannot seem to find it archived anywhere obvious on the World-Wide Web.)

Comment: There are pdfs of a few issues at #89 here http://www.kenmeyerjr.com/ink-stains.html

Comment: @Buzz  Thank you.   The lines are not exactly as I rmembered them, which I guess makes my little rhyme a ittle more oriiginal.